# How to Use Delphi TRegEx to replace a particular capture group?

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to use TRegex in Delphi XE7 to do a search and replace in a string.

The string looks like this "@FXXX(b, v," and I want to replace the second integer value v.
For example: 
  @F037(594,2027,-99,-99,0,0,0,0)

might become
  @F037(594,Fred,-99,-99,0,0,0,0)

I am a newbie at RegEx but made up this pattern that seems to work fine for finding the match and identifying the right capturing group for the "2027" (the part below in parentheses).  Here it is:

@F\d{3}(\s*\d{1,5}\s*,\s*(\d{1,5})\s*,

My problem is that I cannot work out how to replace just the captured group "2027" using the Delphi TRegEx implementation.  I am getting rather confused about TMatch and TGroup and how to use them.  Can anyone suggest some sample code?  I also suspect I am not understanding the concept of backreferences.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Uses
   RegularExpressions;

//The function that does the actual replacement
function TForm6.DoReplace(const Match: TMatch): string;
begin
  //This causes the whole match to be replaced.
  //@F037(594,2027,-99,-99,0,0,0,0) becomes  Fred-99,-99,0,0,0,0)
  //How to just replace the first matched group (ie 2027)?
  If Match.Success then
     Result := 'Fred';
end;


//Code to set off the regex replacement based on source text in Edit1 and put the result back into Memo1
//Edit1.text set to  @F037(594,2027,-99,-99,0,0,0,0)

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  regex: TRegEx;
  Pattern: string;
  Evaluator: TMatchEvaluator;

begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  Pattern := '@F\d{3}\(\s*\d{1,5}\s*,\s*(\d{1,5})\s*,';
  RegEx.Create(Pattern);
  Evaluator := DoReplace;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(RegEx.Replace(Edit1.Text, Pattern, Evaluator));
end;
```

Comment: Capture those parts you need to keep, and use backreferences to them in the replacement pattern. Only match (and do not capture) what you need to remove. Try [`(@F\d{3}\(\s*\d{1,5}\s*,\s*)\d{1,5}(\s*,)` pattern and replace with `\1Fred\2`](https://regex101.com/r/8EUmya/1).

Comment: Thanks - I think my main issue is with how to implement in the Delphi code.  There is not much in the Delphi documentation.  Can you give any guidance on that?

Comment: @CHEAPS TRegex has an overload replace method that doesn't use TMatchEvaluator, but a pattern (string) for replacing. You might want to use this with the patterns given by Wiktor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using regex replacements, the whole matched content will be replaced. You have access to the whole match, captured groups and named captured groups.

There are two different ways of doing this in Delphi.

You are currently using an Evaluator, that is a object method containing instructions what to replace. Inside this method you have access to the whole match content. The result will be the replacement string.
This way is useful if vanilla regex is not capable of things you want to do in the replace (e.g. increasing numbers, changing charcase)

There is another overload Replace method that uses a string as replacement. As you want to do a basic regex replace here, I would recommend using it.
In this string you can backreference to your matched pattern (`$0` for whole match, `$Number` for captured groups, `${Name}` for named capturing groups), but also add whatever characters you want.

So you can capture everything you want to keep in groups and then backreference is as recommended in [Wiktors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) comment.
As you are doing a single replace, I would als recommend using the class function TRegex.Replace instead of creating the Regex and then replacing.

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(
  TRegex.Replace(
    Edit1.Text, 
    '(@F\d{3}\(\s*\d{1,5}\s*,\s*)\d{1,5}(\s*,)', 
    '$1Fred$2'));
```

PCRE regex also supports `\K` (omits everything matched before) and lookaheads, which can be used to capture exactly what you want to replace, like

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(
  TRegex.Replace(
    Edit1.Text, 
    '@F\d{3}\(\s*\d{1,5}\s*,\s*\K\d{1,5}(?=\s*,)', 
    'Fred'));
```